# What benefits are there to use Kafka Connect to write to S3 from Kafka?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm just curious if it's not straight forward to write my own code to read from Kafka using the Kafka Consumer API and use the AWS SDK to write to S3? Are there a lot of non-obvious complications to deal with?

I'm asking since Kafka Connect seems to be the most suggested way to write to S3 from Kafka.

Comment: Hi @Glide, I would like to know if you've learned anything new or how you proceeded with your project. I am in a similar position where Confluent's S3 connector does not meet all my needs therefore I am considering writing my own as an ordinary Kafka consumer. There seems to be a lot of legitimate reasons to avoid Connect. Avoiding Java, avoiding configuration via REST APIs, lack of flexibility in terms of writing to multiple buckets. And on..

Answer (score 3):

You might have seen it mentioned before as an analogy, so I'll use it here too: you may think of Connect as a *high-level* framework of Kafka producers and consumers that aim to integrate your data with Kafka using Sources and Sinks (the high-level equivalents of producers and consumers respectively in Connect). A variety of such Sources and Sinks, briefly Connectors, in already [available](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/).

Specifically, with respect to data export from Kafka to Amazon S3, there are a few connectors already available, and since I'm in part responsible for the [latest one](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud), allow me to mention a few advantages in using it. (Hopefully this will answer your question about whether it is more or less straightforward to implement all these features from scratch).

I will group my arguments in comparison to writing a program directly based on consumers roughly in two categories:

### Pros offered by the Connect Framework

> - Transparent and scalable execution on a cluster.
> - Fault tolerant execution, same as with groups of Kafka consumers (the advantage is that get fault-tolerance without having to write the code)
> - A REST interface to start and stop connectors.
> - A small set of metrics (which will be expanded soon to a full set of performance and operational metrics).
> - Overall, define simple and intuitive streaming data flows that include Sources, simple transformations on your data ([SMTs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms)) and Sinks.

### Pros offered by the S3 Connector

> - Multiple formatters (currently exporting binary .avro files and text .json files)
> - Support of structured or unstructured data, with modes for schema evolution for the former.
> - A gamut of partitioners: Size, time, or field based, which you can use as base classes to build your own custom partitioners that fit
>     your use case, if they don't do exactly what you want out-of-the-box.
> - Exactly-once semantics for most of the use cases of the partitioners above (meaning that, if you reprocess your data, or you recover from a
>     failure, you won't see duplicate records in S3).
> - Easily configurable.
> - Active support from the community (which your classes might also end up having if you open-source them).

Overall, you won't have to write from scratch and maintain code that many others (like you) want to use. Furthermore, if you find that one or more features are missing, you can contribute these features in the open source S3 Connector.

Comment: I have two questions to your helpful feedback. 1) For Kafka Connect, you mentioned "the advantage is that get fault-tolerance without having to write the code". I thought by using the same group with Kafka Consumer, Kafka handles fault tolerance automatically. Could you elaborate how Kafka Connect gives you more fault tolerance than Consumer API? In other words, what would require to get the same level of fault tolerance as Kafka Connect when using only Kafka Consumer API?

Comment: 2) I have to do add custom logic before saving the S3 message. As others have mentioned, Kafka Connect exposes transformations.properties to add extra logic on top. But what if that does not suit my needs. Would you recommend just updating the `S3Connector` source code - maybe the `S3SinkTask:put` method to suit my needs?

Comment: 1) That's where I was getting at when I was writing:  *without having to write the code*. Connect offers you the same fault tolerance as Kafka consumer (wanted to stress that this feature is not absent in Connect) but you don't have to write the code that is using the consumers. Indeed fault tolerance comes with consumer groups as well.

Comment: 2)Yes, my initial suggestion for something as popular as this is to try using Connect and the S3 Connector. This connector will evolve with time to become even more robust, full-featured and efficient. I think it'd be a pity to miss such improvements (even if you now write a consumer app to do exactly what the connector already does) and try to stay up to date. Adding your own custom module to the S3 Connector might be more maintainable for you. But you might want to contribute such additions too. Also, yes, the general idea is to write SMTs and use Connect for what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of advantages:

- Connect can be deployed in a distributed fashion and thus scales
- Connect is fault-tolerant
- You just configure the connector and use it (no coding required)
- If you update, you don't need to update any code (you did not write any)

Of course, you can write your own consumer application that write to S3, but why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: If the Kafka message has to be "massaged" before writing to s3, is it possible to do so with Connect? To my knowledge Kafka Connect only provides a binary to be executed.

Comment: You can check connect single message transforms.  Check below link for more information.Link1 -  http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/release-notes.html?highlight=transforms#single-message-transform,   Link2 -https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-66%3A+Single+Message+Transforms+for+Kafka+Connect

Comment: Also check out the AK docs about single message transformations: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax If I want to do something more involved to the data I'm saving to s3, that is difficult/impossible to do via using those transformation properties, would you recommend me to extend/modify the S3Connector source code? Maybe specifically the `S3SinkTask:put` code. I'm asking to make sure there's no non-obvious gotchas and if it'd be straightforward to go down the S3Connector modification route.

Comment: I am not familiar with the connector internals... So I cannot give any further advice. You might want to ask for advice on the Kafka mailing list: http://kafka.apache.org/contact